# How do I fix 'mail: command not found' on OpenSuse 12.1?

Tags: email, opensuse

I'm sure this is a simple question but I've spent a long time Googleing to no end.  I'm simply trying to send an email from commmand line in OpenSuse12.1 using a "default" mail program that is available on most standard linuxes.  As I understand it 'mail' is that program, but that only returns 'command not found'.  I've searched for mail in Yast but only came up with lots of third-party programs.

Comment: Postfix is installed. Sendmail is not.  Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sendmail and Postfix are Mail Transport Agents (MTAs), you want a mail user agent (MUA).

The package you are looking for is called [`mailx`](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17188965/dir/opensuse/com/mailx-12.5-1.8.x86_64.rpm.html).

However - `mail` has an arcane and awful user interface, so if you want anything more than sending email from the command-line I highly recommend using `mutt` or `alpine` instead. Additionally, if you want to send attachments using the command line, `mutt` is a much better option.